# Intellij cannot resolve symbol inside java comments

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I can't find the option inside the settings to tell Intellij that I'm not interested in telling me that there are "not resolved symbols" inside comments. We have to deal with huge legacy codes, where the code contains references to not existing params or functions.

For example in the code snippet ...

```java
/**
* Some comment bla bla
* @param name
*/
public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
   // ...
}
```

... it would tell "cannot resolve param name". The code is undergone heavy refactoring and the comments are of no interest in this case. Where in the settings is the option to disable these notifications?

Comment: If you disable those warnings, you'd lose notification of places where you actually want to be told where something is wrong. Personally I'd take the hit of a few hours of boring work to either remove or fix the comments.

Comment: I agree with Jon. Or even stronger, the refactoring process should include Javadoc comments in the first place.

Comment: Come on, just tell me where the option is. I know that refactoring should include also comments, but this is dead code in the end. In a few years nobody will care.

Comment: In my experience, things that you consider dead code that will be gone in a few years, and thus doesn't need to be improved or fixed, will be the code that lives the longest in a project. Alternatively, if the comments are "of no interest", just remove them instead of dragging their dead weight and incorrectness along, possibly causing confusion for future maintainers.

Comment: Just fix the problem causing the warning....make sure the `@param` name (`name`) is the same as the parameter name (`firstName`) used for the `setFirstName()` method of which the JavaDoc is for. In other words, change `name` to `firstName`. You can always expect this type of warning when changing code.

Answer (score 1):

In IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate Edition:

- Open up <kbd>Settings</kbd>
- In the left bar in the settings window, select <kbd>Editor</kbd> → <kbd>Inspections</kbd>
- In the list of inspections, select <kbd>Java</kbd> → <kbd>Javadoc</kbd>

Then uncheck the option *"Declaration has problems in Javadoc references"*.